# JavaScript array return

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
this.runThisFunctionOnCall = function(){
        

    //does something and ends up with these arrays of count 1

    // arrays.length = 1 (always)

    array1;
    array2;
    array3;

    alert(array1.length); // shows 1 here 
                    
    }
```

On a different script page, that includes the above page when I do the below, I have no values in array:

```
this.callingFunction = function(){
            
        this.runThisFunctionOnCall();
        alert(array1.length); shows 0

}
```

Comment: How and where are the variables defined?  This is probably a case where you should include more of your actual code.

Comment: `runThisFunctionOnCall` doesn't return anything.  Does it change a global variable?

Comment: @cap - I presume he wants to know why the reference to array1 works in one place but not the other, but we need more actual code to answer that one accurately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable array1 is a local variable inside the function runThisFunctionCall so you can not see it outside the function and that leads to array1 in your lower code being another array1 and not the same as in the function and having the length 0 because there are no elements in it.

Here is some explaining: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/global_local_variables_scope_javascript.php3

Comment: According to code this "The variable array1 is a local variable inside the function runThisFunctionCall" is simply wrong.
And before "having the length 0" you will get "variable not found" exception. So it is not correct either.